# setDate() not working right?

Tags: google-apps-script

Today is December 5th.

My goal is to get the first and the last day of each of the previous three months in a Google Apps Script.

According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp), `setDate(0)` is supposed to return the last day of the previous month.

Which it is not in my case. It returns the first day of the current month:

```
var d = new Date();      
var dd  = d.setDate(0);
Logger.log(getFormattedDate(dd));
```

This logs

```
20171201
```

Interestingly using `setDate(-1)` **does** return the last day of the previous month (which is different to what the documentation says):

```
 var d = new Date();      
 var dd  = d.setDate(-1);
 Logger.log(getFormattedDate(dd));
```

logs

```
20171130
```

Thinking that I understood the logic behind `setDate(0)` and `setDate(-1)` I wrote my new code, assuming that the documentation is just wrong. But then I got this:

```
 var d = new Date();

 var m_1_last  = d.setDate(-1);
 var m_1_first = d.setDate(0);
 var m_2_last  = d.setDate(-1);

 Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_1_last));
 Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_1_first));
 Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_2_last));
```

I would expect to get this

```
20171130
20171101
20171031 <--
```

But I am getting this

```
20171130
20171101
20170930 <--
```

So, if the current date is the first of the month `d.setDate(-1)` will not return the last day of the previous month, but of the month before that one. `d.setDate(-1)` will only return the last day of the previous month if the current date is after the first of the month.

Do I misunderstand something, or is this a bug?

PS:

`getFormattedDate()` is a helper function and works like this:

```
function getFormattedDate(dateInMilliseconds){
  var timeZone = AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  var d = new Date(dateInMilliseconds);
  return Utilities.formatDate(d, timeZone,'yyyyMMdd');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer?

- `d.setDate(0)` means the last day of the previous month.
- `d.setDate(1)` means the first day of the current month.

So when your script is used, the modified parameters are as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
// var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(Date.now() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Modified

var m_1_last  = d.setDate(0);
var m_1_first = d.setDate(1);
var m_2_last  = d.setDate(0);

Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_1_last));
Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_1_first));
Logger.log(getFormattedDate(m_2_last));
```

#### Result :

```
20171130
20171101
20171031
```

#### Note :

- In order to test this, I used `var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();` instead of `var timeZone = AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

How about modifying the offset of timezone, when `new Date()` is retrieved? Can you try to modify as follows?

#### From :

```
var d = new Date();
```

#### To :

```
var d = new Date(Date.now() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

#### Reference :

- [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: When I use your logic I get this

`20171201` and `20171102 ` and `20171101`

There is something wrong here...

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of ``AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone()``?

Comment: The value is `Europe/Zurich`. What is your value? If you tell me I'll test with that one. Maybe it solves it.

Comment: @alev When ``new Date()`` is retrieved, the timeZone of project's time zone is used. I think that the reason is this. You can see it using View -> View manifests and see it in ``appsscript.json``. For example, can you try to modify your project's time zone from yours to ``"timeZone": "Etc/GMT"`` and try again?

Comment: When you changed the project's timezone, please reopen your script editor.

Comment: I use the AdWords script editor where I don't have access to the manifest, etc. I also can't modify the time zone in any way.  (AdWords scripts use the Google Apps Script engine)

Comment: @alev I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How about modifying the offset of timezone? Please confirm my updated answer. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I got it working with this code `var m_1_firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()-1, 1);`. But it doesn't answer my question really.

Comment: @alev Thank you for your additional information. I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @alev Thank you for your reply. I could also study from your question.  Thank you, too.